# Pass data to dispatchGroup.notify in Swift

Tags: swift, dispatchgroup

I'm downloading some JSON from an API, but there is another prerequisite (an animation) that must be complete before we move to the next screen.

I've decided to use `DispatchGroup` to do this, but also need to have a reload as well.

I've come up with a solution that uses a completion handler that is either `dispatchGroup.leave` or simply moving to the next screen, since we only need to download the data once.

```swift
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
var userName: String?

func fetchData() {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    
    resolveDataRequirements(dispatchGroup.leave)
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
        self?.moveToNextScreen()
    }
}

func resolveDataRequirements(_ completion: @escaping(() -> Void)) {
    api.resolve { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let user):
            self?.userName = user
            completion()
        case .failure:
            break
        }
    }
}

func moveToNextScreen() {
    // move to next screen, but passes the user
}

// reload data, and once the data is downloaded move to next screen
func reloadData() {
    resolveDataRequirements(moveToNextScreen)
}


// the user might choose to fetch data
fetchData()
// now if the user wanted to reload
reloadData()
```

Now the problem is that this is in a view model - so the user String is effectively a state that I wish to eradicate.

Is there any way I can pass the user String to `dispatchGroup.notify` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inout properties and change userName scope like this:

```
func fetchData() {
    var userName = ""
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    
    resolveDataRequirements(dispatchGroup.leave, &userName)
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
        self?.moveToNextScreen(userName)
    }
}

func resolveDataRequirements(_ completion: @escaping(() -> Void), _ userName: inout String) {
    api.resolve { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let user):
            userName = user
            completion()
        case .failure:
            break
        }
    }
}

func moveToNextScreen(_ userName: String) {
    print(userName)
}
```

I just don't understand why you are calling enter() twice and leave() just once

Comment: There is no need for an `inout`, right? just `completion: ((String?) -> Void)`, then `resolveDataRequirements { dispatchGroup.leave(); userName = $0 }` should be enough, no? I guess that the user call `leave()` on the "animation", but it's indeed really strange.

Comment: I understand that he doesn't want to setting "userName" as a global variable when he wrote this "Now the problem is that this is in a view model - so the user String is effectively a state that I wish to eradicate."

When you use userName = $0 i supose that "userName" is global yet right?

Comment: No, it’s still local to fetchData() and valid only in that scope.

Comment: Ah ok! Works too.